# Delete iTerm saved window arrangement

Tags: iterm2

I have saved a window arrangement in iTerm2 that I want to remove.  I found this file:
~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
but it isn't really editable.

How can I delete a window arrangement?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You don't need to edit the `.plist` file.

1. Open up iTerm2.
2. Select iTerm menu > Preferences…
3. Select the Arrangements tab.
4. Select an arrangement from the list.
5. Use the `-` button to delete the arrangement (see the screen shot).
6. Get a nice cup of tea and a biscuit.

[image: Whomp that sucker!]

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: There should be bonus points for cute phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

**Updates on Jan 2024 (iTerm version 3.4.21)** The UI has slightly changed.

#### To open the Preferences menu

**Option 1: iTerm Setting** As mentioned in the above answer *(with a minor change)*

iTerm2 menu -> **Settings (cmd+,)** *(Not preferences anymore*)

**Option2: Alternatively, while editing Profiles**

1. Click the Profiles Menu -> Open Profile
2. Select a Profile (or Default)
3. Click Edit Profiles button
4. The 5th Tab is Arrangements (screenshot below)
5. Get a nice cup of tea and a biscuit *(still valid in 2024)*!

[image]